# Maxium call stack size exeeded when refreshing browser with socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I've been trying to figure out why my Node js server keeps crashing when I refresh the browser.
On the initial connect to the websocket everything works fine and connects as normal... however when I refresh the browser my server immediately crashes with this error...

```
E:\Back\node_modules\socket.io-parser\build\cjs\is-binary.js:28
function hasBinary(obj, toJSON) {
                  ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at hasBinary (E:Back\node_modules\socket.io-parser\build\cjs\is-binary.js:28:19)
    at hasBinary (E:\Back\node_modules\socket.io-parser\build\cjs\is-binary.js:49:63)
    at hasBinary (E:\Back\node_modules\socket.io-parser\build\cjs\is-binary.js:49:63)
    at hasBinary (E:\Back\node_modules\socket.io-parser\build\cjs\is-binary.js:49:63)
    at hasBinary (E:\Back\node_modules\socket.io-parser\build\cjs\is-binary.js:49:63)
    at hasBinary (E:\Back\node_modules\socket.io-parser\build\cjs\is-binary.js:49:63)
    at hasBinary (E:\Back\node_modules\socket.io-parser\build\cjs\is-binary.js:49:63)
    at hasBinary (E:\Back\node_modules\socket.io-parser\build\cjs\is-binary.js:49:63)
    at hasBinary (E:\Back\node_modules\socket.io-parser\build\cjs\is-binary.js:49:63)
    at hasBinary (E:\Back\node_modules\socket.io-parser\build\cjs\is-binary.js:49:63)
```

I think I've narrowed down the issue to the disconnect part of the code, however cannot determine why it would crash since there isn't much logic in there yet its the bare miniumum...

server.js file

```
export const io = new Server(4006, {
    cors: {
        origin: "http://192.168.0.19:5173",
        credentials: true
    }
})

const getSocketByUserId = (userId) => {
    let socket = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < clientSocketIds.length; i++) {
        if (clientSocketIds[i].userId == userId) {
            socket = clientSocketIds[i].socket;
            break;
        }
    }
    return socket;
}
io.use(async (socket, next) => {
    console.log(socket.handshake.auth.userId)
    if(socket.handshake.auth.userId) {
        messageController.socketUserAuthentication(socket, next)
    } else {
        console.log('Already connected')
    }
    console.log('Authenticated')
}).on('connection', socket => {
    console.log('conected')
    messageController.storeConnectedUser(socket)
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        messageController.handleUserDisconnect(socket)
    });
    socket.on('create', function (data) {
        console.log("create room")
        socket.join(data.room);
        let withSocket = getSocketByUserId(data.withUserId);
        socket.broadcast.to(withSocket.id).emit("invite", { room: data })
    });
    socket.on('joinRoom', function (data) {
        socket.join(data.room.room);
    });

    socket.on('message', function (data) {
        socket.broadcast.to(data.room).emit('message', data);
    })
});
```

message.controller.js

```
import userModel from '../user/user.model.js'
import emailModel from '../emails/email.model.js'
import calendarModel from '../calendar/calendar.model.js'
import { HttpException } from '../../utility/HttpException.utility.js'
import { validationResult } from 'express-validator'
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs'
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'
import { logger } from '../../utility/logger.js'
import { isEmpty } from '../../utility/common.utility.js'
import { addHours, parseISO } from 'date-fns'
import _ from 'lodash'
import { io } from '../../server.js'
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid'
import { user_type } from '../../utility/userRoles.utility.js'

dotenv.config()


class messageController {
    constructor() {
        this.connectedUsers = []
        this.clientSocketIds = []

    }
    test = () => {
        console.log('CLIENT SOCKET IDS',this.clientSocketIds)
        console.log('CONNECTED USERS',this.connectedUsers)
    }
    getSocketByUserId = (userId) => {
        let socket = ''
        for (let i = 0; i < this.clientSocketIds.length; i++) {
            if (clientSocketIds[i].userId == userId) {
                socket = clientSocketIds[i].socket
                break
            }
        }
        return socket
    }
    socketUserAuthentication = async (socket, next) => {
        try {
            this.test()
            console.log('Authenticate')
            // console.log(socket.handshake.headers.bearer)
            const authHeader = socket.handshake.auth.token
            // const authHeader = socket.handshake.headers.bearer
            const id = socket.handshake.auth.userId
            console.log(authHeader)
            console.log(id)

            const bearer = 'Bearer '

            if (!authHeader) {
                console.log(authHeader)
                return new HttpException(401, 'Access denied. No credentials sent!')
            }

            const token = authHeader.replace(bearer, '')
            const secretKey = process.env.SECRET_JWT || ""

            // Verify Token
            const decoded = jwt.verify(token, secretKey)
            const user = await userModel.findUser({ userId: decoded.user_id })

            if (!user) {
                return new HttpException(401, 'Authentication failed!')
            }
            // SOMETHING WITH ROLES
            const ownerAuthorized = id == user.userId
            if (!ownerAuthorized && roles.length && !roles.includes(user.user_type)) {
                return new HttpException(401, 'Unauthorized')
            }
            socket.currentUser = user;
            // console.log(socket.currentUser)
            return next();
        } catch (e) {
            e.status = 401;
            console.log(e)
            next(e);
        }
    }

    storeConnectedUser = (socket) => {
        // , socket.currentUser.contacts
        // io.emit('message', socket.currentUser.first_name)

        // logger.info(`User has connected with the ID: ${socket.currentUser.userId}`)
        this.clientSocketIds.push({ socket: socket, userId: socket.currentUser.userId, username: socket.currentUser.username })
        this.connectedUsers = this.connectedUsers.filter(item => item.userId != socket.currentUser.userId)
        this.connectedUsers.push({ username: socket.currentUser.username, userId: socket.currentUser.userId, uuid: uuidv4(), socket: socket })
        // logger.info('User stored: ' + socket.currentUser.userId)
        return socket
    }

    handleUserDisconnect = (socket) => {
        // logger.info('User has disonnected: ' + socket.currentUser.userId)
        this.connectedUsers = this.connectedUsers.filter(item => item.socketId != socket.id)
        io.emit('updateUserList', this.connectedUsers)
        return socket
    }
}

export default new messageController
```

I would normally expect to disconnect from the server when refreshing and then automatically sign back in but it crashes the server instead and until restart unable to join.

***EDIT**
After removing the line `io.emit('updateUserList', this.connectedUsers)` it appears to stop crashing...

Answer (score 0):

I had a typo... `this.connectedUsers = this.connectedUsers.filter(item => item.socketId != socket.id)` intead of `item.socketId` it should've been `item.socket.id` I was filtering a non existent id so I'm guessing when they  disconnect and I was trying to emit this.connectedUsers it was undefined or something and then crashed when sending that to the user.